# How to find overlapping time slices of serveral key-value elements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to find out if I have overlapping time slices that have the same id and the same name. 
In the following example, the entries with id=2 and name=c overlaps.
Entry with id=1 is just for demonstration of a good case.

Given table:

```
+---+------+-------+------------+--------------+
|id | name | value | validFrom  |  validTo     |
+---+------+-------+------------+--------------+
|1  | a    | 12    | 2019-01-01 |  9999-12-31  |
|1  | b    | 34    | 2019-01-01 |  2019-10-31  |
|1  | b    | 35    | 2019-11-01 |  9999-12-31  |
|1  | c    | 13    | 2019-01-01 |  2025-12-31  |
|2  | a    | 49    | 2019-01-01 |  9999-12-31  |
|2  | b    | 99    | 2019-01-01 |  2034-12-31  |
|2  | c    | 75    | 2019-01-01 |  2019-10-31  |
|2  | c    | 84    | 2019-10-28 |  9999-12-31  |
|n  | ...  | ...   | ...        |  ...         |
+---+------+-------+------------+--------------+
```

expected output:

```
+---+------+
|id | name |
+---+------+
|2  | c    |
+---+------+
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the overlapping rows using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.value <> t.value and
                    t2.validTo > t.validFrom and
                    t2.validFrom < t.validTo
             );
```

If you just want the `id`/`name` combinations:

```
select distinct t.id, t.name
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and
                    t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.value <> t.value and
                    t2.validTo > t.validFrom and
                    t2.validFrom < t.validTo
             );
```

You can also do this with a cumulative max:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(validTo) over (partition by id, name 
                                order by validFrom
                                rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                               ) as prev_validTo
      from t
     ) t
where prev_validTo >= validFrom;
```

Comment: The OP can include the equal on the date's comparisons (`>=` instead of `>`) if the period overlaps are to consider the boundary days.

Comment: @EzLo . . . That is a good point.  Based on the sample data, I don't think the boundaries should be the same.

Comment: I am fairly certain that if you do not include a comparison of the value columns (i.e. t.value <> t2.value)  your queries will return every row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the third example works for me like a charm. Unfortunately example one returns all entries (also single rows). Example two also, but cause the `distinct` any id-name combination is returned just once.

Comment: @JM_ . . . That was true of the first two (which have been fixed), but not the third.

Comment: It should consider boundary days, so thanks for your comment @EzLo.
Thank you all for your help!